# Preg match regex output https// instead of https://

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm not sure how to ask this but I am having a problem with  output URL showing `https//example.com`

Below is my code, someone please i need assistance, I am trying to achieve `https://example.com` while I got `https//example.com`

Am i missing anything on the regex or something..?

Thanks.

```
 shuffle($randurl);

    $smtp_email = $smtp_user;
    $smtp_user = explode("@", $smtp_user) [0];

    $randurls = array_shift($randurl);

    preg_match('@^(?:https://)?([^/]+)@i', $randurls, $matches);
    $host = $matches[1];

    $host = explode('.', $host);
    $host = $host[0];

    $email64 = base64_encode($email);
    $base64url = base64_decode($randurls);

    if ($redirect == 1)
    {
        $randurls = "$randurls?email=" . urlencode($email64) . "";
    }
    else if ($redirect == 2)
    {
        $randurls = "$randurls?a=" . urlencode($email64) . "";
    }
    else if ($redirect == 3)
    {
        $randurls = "$randurls?email=" . urlencode($email) . "";
```

Comment: In your pattern, the whole https:// part is optional, so if it can not match the negated character class matches any character except a forward slash. Note that it can also match `https:://` in this case. See what your pattern matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/ln9xif/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Please review the code again, I edited it to the default code, My OUTPUT was `https//example.com`, instead of `https://example.com` ..Thanks for your. response

Answer (score 1):

In regex, colon symbol is used for character classes. Such as [:alpha:]  represents an alphabetic character. Your regex is reading (:https:) as a singular expression. I suggest looking over this to get a better idea on handling this.
https://www.codexpedia.com/regex/regex-symbol-list-and-regex-examples/
Since I do not actually know what you are trying to achieve, I can not give a more definitive answer on how to get whatever you are trying to get.

Comment: I am trying to achieve "https://" While I got "https//" How do i write the regex to include the semicolon in between "https" and "://"

Answer (score 1):

Find by http and optional s appended by a colon and keep (replace by)  the match without colon.

**Note:** A preg_match finds a pattern, does not replace it.

```
$pattern = '/(https?):/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', 'http://www.example.com'), PHP_EOL;
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', 'https://www.example.com'), PHP_EOL;
```

```
http//www.example.com
https//www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the protocol and assert `//` to the right.

In the replacement use `:`

```
\bhttps?\K(?=//)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RJ6pS3/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/eXa4d)

```
$re = '`\bhttps?\K(?=//)`';
$str = 'https//example.com';
$subst = ':';

echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Output

```
https://example.com
```

You could also use a capture group, and replace with `$1:$2`

```
\b(https?)(//)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hKM9f/1)